# Enter button in AutoCompleteTextBox not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using an AutoCompleteTextBox textbox(from over here: https://wpfautocomplete.codeplex.com/) in my C#/WPF app.
Code is as per  below.When I hit "enter" or "tab" button after typing text in the textbox,I dont see SelectedProductName getting set.
Could you advise what am I missing here please?

Thanks.

xaml:

```
<wpf:AutoCompleteTextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                     Height="25"
                                     Width="320"
                                     Margin="1,0"
                                     DisplayMember="Name"
                                     Text="{Binding Path=ProductName, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                     Watermark="Search"
                                     IconPlacement="Left"
                                     IconVisibility="Visible"
                                     Provider="{Binding SuggestionProvider}"
                                     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedProductName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                     x:Name="Actb" TabIndex="0" >
```

ViewModel:

```
public ProductNameViewModel SelectedProductName
        {
            get
            {
                return m_selectedProductName;
            }
            set
            {
//Invoke a method on WCF Service to get Product details
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you created your own AutoCompleteTextBox? if yes, then you should write the behaviour to select item on Enter or tab.

Comment: Are you talking about typing input that corresponds to an actually existing item or do you expect to have arbitrary input turned into a new item?

Comment: TwoWay binding instead of oneway to source?

Comment: Hi Grek40,Yes, this is about typing input that corresponds to an already existing item. Thanks.